# What are the common ID Card Photo Aspect Ratios?

Tags: portrait, aspect-ratio

What are the aspect ratios used for ID Card Photos/Portrait Images of a Single Person?

Answer (score 2):

This differ by country:

- in UK you need 45mm X 35mm (ratio 1:1.285)
- same for Germany, France, Bulgaria, Czehia (probably entire EU)
- 22mm X 35mm (1" and 1 3/8") in USA (ratio 1:1.59)
- 50mm X 70mm (2" X 2 3/4") in Canada (ratio 1:1.4)
- 45mm X 35mm for ID card, 25mm X 30mm driver license in Japan (ratio 1:1.285)
- 33mm X 48mm in China (ratio 1:1.454)

P.S. I am not aware of practice to take photo of multiply people for ID card

Comment: Thanks.. but I'm just referring to the aspect ratio,not size.

Comment: It can be calculated easy. Let me add it to the answer

Comment: Thanks..........

Comment: Romeo, where did you get this information?

Comment: @osullic, from search engines, found a lot of sources :) Mostly government sites